# How to make Expand work right in a function definition?

Tags: function-construction

This works just fine:

```
Derivative[n_, 1][g][x_, v_] := D[g[x, v], {x, n + 2}]/2 + D[D[g[x, v], x]^2/2, {x, n}];
h = Expand[D[g[x, v], {v, 3}]]
```

I would like to make the Expand part of the definition to clean up my code.  But putting Expand in the definition returns a not-fully Expanded expression:

```
Derivative[n_, 1][g][x_, v_] := Expand[D[g[x, v], {x, n + 2}]/2 + D[D[g[x, v], x]^2/2, {x, n}]];
h = D[g[x, v], {v, 3}]
```

And to my surprise, FixedPoint[Expand,.] doesn't work either.

```
Derivative[n_, 1][g][x_, v_] := FixedPoint[Expand, D[g[x, v], {x, n + 2}]/2 + D[D[g[x, v], x]^2/2, {x, n}]];
h = D[g[x, v], {v, 3}]
```

How can I make this work?  (BTW, I wasn't sure what tag to use on this Question either)